# Trying to display a rectangular array (update)

Tags: vb.net, arrays

I'm trying to do a tic-tac-toe console application for practice. I created a case statement for the user to pick which square they want to fill in.

```
Public Class TwoDi
    Shared Sub twodimension()
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to go first?")
        first = Console.ReadLine()

        If first = "yes" Then
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a X or O.")
            x2 = Console.ReadLine()

            Console.WriteLine("Pick a spot.")
            pickone(x2)
        End If
    End Sub

    Shared Sub pickone(ByVal x As String)
        Dim choice As String
        Dim tic(2, 2) As String
        Dim x2 As String
        Dim bound0 As Integer = tic.GetUpperBound(0)
        Dim bound1 As Integer = tic.GetUpperBound(1)
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim x1 As Integer
        Dim populate As String = "n"

        For i = 0 To bound0
          For x1 = 0 To bound1
            Console.Write("{0}", show)
          Next
         Console.WriteLine()
        Next

        x2 = x
        choice = Console.ReadLine()

        Select Case choice
            Case "middle"    //putting in one case statement for example.
                choice = "middle"
                tic(1, 1) = x2        
        End Select

        Console.Write("" & vbLf & "Pick a spot.")
        pickone(x2)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now I tried a few loops to update the display to show the 3x3 2-d array. Specifically this one:

```
For i = 0 To bound0
    For x1 = 0 To bound1
        Console.Write("{0}", tic(bound0, bound1))
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

I prepopulate the 3x3 grid with "n" but when I run the loop it just shows a single x or o and not even spaced correctly.

Also a somewhat seperate question, when I loop to run a block of code again, is it best practice to just to call the Sub/Function again?

Comment: I learned visual basis (in 1995, Windows 3.1) writing a program to solve the 15 numbers in 4 by 4 square, shifting numbers around via the empty square. I finally got it. There's hope if you continue trying and don't forget to read MANY samples in MSDN

Comment: Yeah I'm really trying, I have been trying to figure out this logic for days now and trying different possibilities but nothing really comes close. I'll keep trying of course but just at least be lead in the right direction.

Comment: Since this post, I have been thinking about it for days, I'm beginning to think there's no way to display each location individually using a looping array since all the loop does is loop and populate it with whatever you enter for the output.

Comment: I was hoping theres a way to do it with a loop but I don't think its logically possible. Only way to do it is to assign each position in the array and string format it to display properly. 

That was one of my alternative solution which I hope I don't have to use.  I have no issues doing doing it that way but I was hoping for a more efficient and compact code using an array.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the *"all filled with X or O depending if I pick a X or O"* part:

Did you really mean to type `Console.Write("{0}", tic(1, 1))` instead of maybe this?

```
For i = 0 To bound0
     For x1 = 0 To bound1
       Console.Write("{0}", tic(i, x1))
     Next
   Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

Comment: Also, for what its worth, you could simply write `Console.Write(tic(i, x1))`, no need for the format string version in this case.